# Want to display two string value in two different tkinter label

Tags: python, tkinter, serial-port, raspberry-pi3

I make code for displaying two serial read string in two different label using tkinter GUI..
My code is running and window also popped up but values are not displaying..
Help me to solve this issue..
Here is my code

```
import serial
import tkinter 
from tkinter import *
import time
class SerialViewer(Tk):
 def _init_(self):
      self.win = Tk()
      self.ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0',9600)
 def makewindow (self):
      frame1 =Frame(self.win)
      frame1.pack()
      self.v=StringVar()
      self.v.set=('default')
      label=Label(frame1,textvariable=self.v,relief=RAISED)
      label.pack(side=LEFT)
      frame2 = Frame(self.win)
      frame2.pack()
      self.d=StringVar()
      self.d.set=('default')
      label=Label(frame2,textvariable=self.d,relief=RAISED)
      label.pack(side=RIGHT)
 def update(self):
       print(self.ser.write("*01T%"))
       data=self.ser.readline(self.ser.inWaiting())
       self.v.set(data)
       time.sleep(2)
       print(self.ser.write('*00T%'))
       data1=self.ser.readline(self.ser.inWaiting())
       self.d.set(data1)
       self.win.after(100,self.update)
 def run (self):
       self.makewindow()
       self.update()
       self.win.mainloop()
app=SerialViewer()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: change \_init\_ to \_\_init\_\_. Notice the two underscores.

Comment: @HNMN,File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1283, in mainloop
    self.tk.mainloop(n)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2101, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2101, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2101, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
  [Previous line repeated 496 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comment that the method _init_ needs to be changed to __init__ and the recursion error is coming because the __init__ method of parent class wasn't called. Please add that call like below:

```
class SerialViewer(Tk):
    def _init_(self):
        super(SerialViewer, self).__init__() # Call the initializer method of parent class
        self.win = Tk()
        self.ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0',9600)
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: ,,this edit works and a window popped up..but its not reading values from seial port..is der any fault in def update(self) function??

Comment: Please tell me which serial library you are using.

Comment: default which is there in my Pi3 i.e import serial

Comment: The issue is that there are two Tk objects are being created, just remove self.win variable and replace its usage to work with self object itself.